# Why are the last two instructions unreachable code?

Tags: java, unreachable-code

Eclipse spots them as unreachable code, which apparently is a code that will never be read for there's no path to reach it, but I don't see why. The instructions are inside a main() method

```
    //leemos
    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    Alumno alumnoLeido = null;
    String cadena ="";
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(6,1);
    while(true){
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("alumnos.txt");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            alumnoLeido = (Alumno) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            cadena = "Alumno " + alumnoLeido.getNombre() + " " + alumnoLeido.getApellido() + " vive en " 
            + alumnoLeido.getDireccion() + " y tiene una beca de " + alumnoLeido.getBeca() + " euros \r\n";
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    area.append(cadena);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, area, "Alumnos",1);
```

Comment: while(true) - True is always true unless it's forced to be 'false' or make it to 'break'.

Comment: @SajalDutta What do you mean by `unless it's forced to be 'false'`? Are you saying that the primitive `boolean` value `true` can be changed to `false`?

Comment: How is it ever going to exit the while loop? It is always going to be true, so the lines after the while loop would never be reached.

Comment: @JimmyStallion You can use a boolean variable which can be initially true and inside the while scope the value of the variable can be changed. Hence, terminating while loop or just use break when you need to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(true)` is an infinite loop. Without a `break`, the loop will never terminate and allow the following code to execute. So, you will never reach the remaining statements.

Answer (score 3):

They are unreachable because your `while` loop will never terminate.